# CSS3 Box Shadow with oddly shaped shadow

Tags: css, html, svg

I am trying to get a shadow that is similar to the one here in this image.
[image: Box with shadow]

I am actually not sure this is a shadow though I believe it is.
My question is how could I achieve this kind of effect with CSS3?

Comment: ...So what's your *question*? To work out *exactly* what it is, we'd need the actual code, not just an image.

Answer (score 0):

i think it might use 'border-image' attribute, or use '::after' or '::before' element to make up it. :)